# Powershell xml scraping

Tags: xml, powershell, powerbi

So I'm trying to generate a streaming dataset in Power BI, so that I can have a tab in teams that constantly updates with data from my companies database. The way I pull the data is through our platform API that generates a file (XML,JSON,CSV) and a URL based on the query. I want to use PowerShell to **scrape** the XML and then push that data to the dashboard in Power Bi, but I have absolutely no experience with any of this, so I'm completely baffled as to where to start.

I'm only generating a prototype dashboard for my company using a log of Hours worked by the Date those hours were entered.

Here's part of the generated xml file

```xml
<RECORDS>
<COUNT>332</COUNT>
<DISPLAY_LIST_START>1</DISPLAY_LIST_START>
<DISPLAY_LIST_STOP>332</DISPLAY_LIST_STOP>
<STOP>332</STOP>
<RECORD>
<SESSION_ID><![CDATA[HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta]]></SESSION_ID>
<FIELD>
<VALUE>6</VALUE>
</FIELD>
<FIELD>
<VALUE><![CDATA[04/23/2018]]></VALUE>
</FIELD>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
<SESSION_ID><![CDATA[HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta]]></SESSION_ID>
<FIELD>
<VALUE>6</VALUE>
</FIELD>
<FIELD>
<VALUE><![CDATA[04/24/2018]]></VALUE>
</FIELD>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
<SESSION_ID><![CDATA[HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta]]></SESSION_ID>
<FIELD>
<VALUE>6</VALUE>
</FIELD>
<FIELD>
<VALUE><![CDATA[04/26/2018]]></VALUE>
</FIELD>
</RECORD>
```

Or the alternate JSON File of the same data:

```json
{"COUNT":"332","DISPLAY_LIST_START":"1","DISPLAY_LIST_STOP":"332","STOP":"332","RECORD":[{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/23/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/24/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/26/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/30/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/01/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/02/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/03/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/07/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/08/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/09/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/10/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/17/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/16/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/15/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/18/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/22/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/23/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/25/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/24/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/29/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/30/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["5.5",["06/05/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/06/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/08/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/12/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/13/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/19/2018"]]}
```

Having all the data I want being labeled as "VALUE" make this extra difficult. But, like I said, it's auto generated by the Company API.

Here's the PowerShell code generated by Power BI

```
$endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/d6cdaa23-930e-49c1-9d2a-0fbe648551b2/datasets/34eaea1e-73b6-4759-ac8b-aaae51708654/rows?noSignUpCheck=1&key=Ur9E0GDrhkp4EwJOF4bCbg7EO7aIve54urjB8M%2BHevG1%2F6pDgRJ47Fvkmx4b%2FcMowlhV18ZYyVtF9pfG%2BM1EQA%3D%3D"
$payload = @{
"Hours" =98.6
"Date Worked" ="2020-07-20T18:40:06.892Z"
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
```

I know this is a lot, and I'm continually looking on tutorials and forums, but I'm kind of drowning.

Comment: For the sample xml in the question - exactly what data are you trying to extract?

Comment: I want to extract the dates and the numbers that represent the hours worked. Like in the first record I want "04/23/2018" and "6". That's 6 hours logged on April 23, 2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that everything is labeled as "VALUE", I personally would use JSON instead of XML because the extraction feels "cleaner".

To extract the data from JSON:

```bsh
# Convert the JSON to a PSObject.
$json = '{"COUNT":"332","DISPLAY_LIST_START":"1","DISPLAY_LIST_STOP":"332","STOP":"332","RECORD":[{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/23/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/24/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/26/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["04/30/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/01/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/02/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/03/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/07/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/08/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/09/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/10/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/17/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/16/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/15/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/18/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/22/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/23/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/25/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["4",["05/24/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/29/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["05/30/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["5.5",["06/05/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/06/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/08/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/12/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/13/2018"]]},{"SESSION_ID":"HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta","FIELD":["6",["06/19/2018"]]}]}' | ConvertFrom-Json

# Iterate each record in the JSON object.
$json.RECORD | % {
  $hours = 0
  $date = ""

  $_.Field | % {
    # If the value of the field matches a date string set the date, else set the hours worked.
    if ($_ -match '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}') {
      $date = "$_"
    }
    else {
      $hours = $_
    }
  }

  # Return a new PSObject with a Date & Hours property.
  New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property (@{
    Date = $date
    Hours = $hours
  })
}
```

If you would like to use XML:

```bsh
$xml = [xml]'<RECORDS><COUNT>332</COUNT><DISPLAY_LIST_START>1</DISPLAY_LIST_START><DISPLAY_LIST_STOP>332</DISPLAY_LIST_STOP><STOP>332</STOP><RECORD><SESSION_ID><![CDATA[HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta]]></SESSION_ID><FIELD><VALUE>6</VALUE></FIELD><FIELD><VALUE><![CDATA[04/23/2018]]></VALUE></FIELD></RECORD><RECORD><SESSION_ID><![CDATA[HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta]]></SESSION_ID><FIELD><VALUE>6</VALUE></FIELD><FIELD><VALUE><![CDATA[04/24/2018]]></VALUE></FIELD></RECORD><RECORD><SESSION_ID><![CDATA[HxNI-Zuc1B2EFAzTS8hx6w7Ek_dbrNCMhYVNI3Ta]]></SESSION_ID><FIELD><VALUE>6</VALUE></FIELD><FIELD><VALUE><![CDATA[04/26/2018]]></VALUE></FIELD></RECORD></RECORDS>'

$xml.Records.RECORD | % {
  $hours = $null
  $date = $_.Field.Value.'#cdata-section'

  $_.Field.VALUE | % {
    if (($_.GetType()).Name -eq "String") {
      $hours = $_
    }
  }

  New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property (@{
    Date = $date
    Hours = $hours
  })
}
```

Comment: When I run the code 

```Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\Users\Hunter\Desktop\jsonStreamer.ps1:27 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand```

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with xml, the safest path is usually xpath. To get hours and date for each `<RECORED>`:

```
$input = [xml]'
[your xml above, validated
'
$hours = $input.SelectNodes(".//RECORD//FIELD[1]/VALUE")

foreach ($hour in $hours)
{
$date = $hour.SelectSingleNode("../following-sibling::FIELD/VALUE")
Write-Host $hour.InnerText , $date.InnerText
}
```

Output:

```
6 04/23/2018
6 04/24/2018
6 04/26/2018
```